# Choose software from Debian repository

Tags: debian, repository, aptitude, iwlwifi, gnupg

How can I choose which software I want to install from a Debian repository? I know that didn't make much sense, let me explain more detail.

I want to install a «unstable» version of `gnupg` with (ECC support), but I'm afraid of adding a «unstable» repository to my `sources.list` file, because it will mess up other sotware when i run:

```
aptitude upgrade
```

In short: I want all other packages to be in stable version, except gnupg.

Comment: You should use apt pinning. See `man apt_preferences`, or more generally, google "apt preferences". "I don't want to access to all other packages in the «non-free» repository". I'm unclear what you mean by "access". What is the problem with adding the non-free repository? You don't; have to install any of the other packages if you don't want to.

Comment: My bad, I was thinking of unstable repository at the same time as i was writing about the non-free repository. Non-free repository will not mess up package versions.

Comment: Would you please delete the post then?

Comment: Why? The second part of the post is still valid. It was just the first part that I mixed up.

Comment: This question feels like it is a dupe, but anyway, I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pinning all packages in unstable is easy. Just add

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 50
```

or similar to `/etc/apt/preferences`.

This will hold back all packages in unstable from upgrade by apt or aptitude. Note that there is nothing magic about 50. From `man apt_preferences`:

> 0 < P < 100
>              causes a version to be installed only if there is no installed version of the package

NOTE: I think this could be better expressed as:

> causes a version to be installed only if there is no installable version of higher priority available.

I.e. if `pkg` is available in your default release, then the unstable version of `pkg` will not be installed by default.

So any number in that range will work.

To install a version from unstable in this case, you will either have to do

```
apt-get install pkg/unstable pkg/dep1 pkg/dep2 ...
```

in which case you will have to add additional dependencies manually (as shown, using `dep1` and `dep2` as examples) if they are not available in your current release version, or

```
apt-get install -t unstable pkg
```

which will automatically take dependencies from unstable, which you probably don't want do to in general. So, be careful with this latter command.